# Chamar método de component em todos os controllers no CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Gostaria de saber como chamar um método de um component que criei no CakePHP 3 em todos os controllers, assim como o Auth que verifica se o usuário ta logado ou não em todas as páginas (controllers). Porém eu quero também poder chamar outro método desse meu component em alguns controllers no `beforeFilter` antes que ele execute o método padrão que sempre var ser executado.

Exemplo:

Em alguns controllers no `beforeFilter` eu permito algumas ações dele com o `$this->Auth->allow('add')` e assim quando o AuthComponent vai verificar se o User ta logado ou não ele ignora porque a página foi definida como permitida, preciso fazer basicamente o mesmo com o component que criei.

Quero realizar determinada ação padrão em todos os controllers, mas poder definir algumas configurações no `beforeFilter` de um controller qualquer antes que a determinidade ação padrão seja executada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui a forma como eu resolvi o meu problema/dilema, para caso alguém precise fazer a mesma coisa que eu.

No `beforeFilter()` do AppController, chamei o método que eu criei do meu Component personalizado para que ele fosse executado em todas as páginas da seguinte forma:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    //some code here...
    $this->MeuComponent->metodoPadrao();
}
```

Depois em qualquer Controller especifico em que eu queira que, algum outro método seja executado antes do `metodoPadrao()`, eu chamo esse método no `beforeFilter()` do Controller da seguinte forma:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->MeuComponent->metodoEspecifico();
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    //some code here...
}
```

Assim o CakePHP executa o `metodoEspecifico()` antes de exutar o `metodoPadrao()`, nos Controllers em que ele é "chamado" antes do `parent::beforeFilter($event)`.